How do I verify this extension formula of a slice map?
I am working through a textbook that states the following equation holds:

Let $A = C_0(G)$ and $\Delta: A \longrightarrow M(A \otimes A)$ be the usual comultiplication $\Delta(f)(t,s) = f(ts)$.  Given a positive $\omega \in A^{*}$, we have that: $$(\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\Delta(f))(s) = \int_{G} \Delta(f)(t,s) \: d\nu(t) \: \: \forall f \in C^{+}_c(G)$$ where $\omega(h) = \int_{G} h(t) \: d\nu(t)$ (so in particular $\nu$ is a finite measure).

It's simple enough to first check that $(\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(g \otimes h)(s) = \int_{G} (g \otimes h)(t,s) \: d\nu(t)$ and so given $\xi \in C_c(G \times G) \subset C_c(G,C_c(G))$, one can get a net $(\xi_i)_i \subset C_c(G) \odot C_c(G)$ such that $\xi_i \longrightarrow \xi$ in the inductive limit topology on $C_c(G \times G)$.  Using the above formula on elementary tensors and the uniform convergence we get quickly that: $$(\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\xi)(s) = \int_{G} \xi(t,s) \: d\nu(t) \: \: \forall \xi \in C_c(G \times G).$$  There are other ways to do this, but this is just what I initially thought of. However now we have $\Delta(f) \in C^{+}_b(G \times G)$ so I can let $\xi_i \longrightarrow \Delta(f)$ strictly where $(\xi_i)_i \subset C_c(G \times G)$.
Now, (the extentsion of) $\omega \otimes \text{id}_A$ is strictly continuous as a map from $C_b(G \times G) \longrightarrow C_b(G)$ so $(\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\xi_i) \longrightarrow (\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\Delta(f))$ strictly in $C_b(G)$, which implies $(\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\xi_i) \longrightarrow (\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\Delta(f))$ pointwise on $G$.  In particular then, we immediately get: $$(\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\Delta(f))(s) = \lim_i (\omega \otimes \text{id}_A)(\xi_i)(s) = \lim_i \int_{G} \xi_i(t,s) \: d\nu(t) \: \: \forall s \in G.$$  Thus, I just need to justify that: $$\lim_i \int_{G} \xi_i(t,s) \: d\nu(t) = \int_{G} \lim_i \xi_i(t,s) \: d\nu(t) \tag{1}.$$  Again, this is because $\xi_i \longrightarrow \Delta(f)$ strictly implies pointwise convergence (and infact uniform convergence on compacta if that matters), so that: $$\int_{G} \lim_i \xi_i(t,s) \: d\nu(t) = \int_{G} \Delta(f)(t,s) \: d\nu(t)$$ like I want.  However, what I currently have is a net $(\xi_{i,s})_i \subset C_c(G)$ where $\xi_{i,s}: t \mapsto \xi_i(t,s)$ converging pointwise to the function $\Delta(f)_s: t \mapsto \Delta(f)(t,s) \in C_c(G)$.
If I knew somehow that the net $(\xi_i)_i$ was uniformly bounded, then I could use the fact that the strict topology on $M(A \otimes A) = C_b(G \times G)$ is metrizable on the set $\{\xi_i,\Delta(f) \: | \: i\}$ and thus pass to a subsequence, which would allow me to use the dominated convergence theorem to show (1).  However without that, I am now sure what to do.  Hence, I am looking to prove that I can choose the net $(\xi_i)$ to be uniformly bounded, but this is proving to be hard to do.  I have tried using the uniform boundedness principle to see if I can find a family of pointwise bounded linear maps $T_i$ such that $\lVert T_i \rVert = \lVert \xi_i \rVert$ for each $i$.
If anyone has an idea of how to solve this, that would be very helpful!

I think the following works: first show this when $\nu$ is compactly supported - you don’t need dominated convergence for this, just directly use the definition of strict topology to show the RHS formula is strictly continuous. Then show the LHS is continuous in $\omega$ while the RHS is continuous in $\nu$.

(Or, really, you can just do this by hand since we’re dealing with functions anyway. Just take $\xi_i$ to be the restriction of $\Delta(f)$ to larger and larger compact sets, extended to elements of $C_c(G \times G)$ of the same norms, via, say, the Tietze extension theorem. Then $\xi_i$ are uniformly bounded by norm of $\Delta(f)$ and from that it is not hard to see $\xi_i \to \Delta(f)$ strictly.)
